# Categorías de productos en php

Tags: php, mysql, crud

Tengo una tabla llamada **categorías** la cual tiene dos columnas (id, name). Tengo otra tabla de productos llamada **ítems** con varios campos (id, descripción, etc)

Tengo un `crud` de productos  y a cada producto en el `crud` tiene la opción de agregarle una categoría.

Lo que quisiera hacer mostrar en un archivo los productos segmentados por categorías, por ejemplo que al agregar un producto en el `crud`, este se integre en el archivo a la categoría que pertenece, así el usuario mediante un menú de navegación puede navegar entre las categorías llamando el `id` de la categoría y ver los productos de esa categoría.

Ejemplo:

```
----------------
(Hamburguesas)
Hamburguesa con queso
Hamburguesa Sencilla
Hamburguesa Doble
---------------------
(Ensaladas)
Ensalada de la casa
Ensalada Capressa
Ensalada Premium
----------------
(Bebidas)
Coca Cola 
Fanta Naranja
Te frio
```

Acá muestro el código que tengo actualmente:

```
<?php 
    //error_reporting(0);
    require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/php-menu/admin/incluir/database.php'; 
    $db = Database::connect();
    $categorias = $db->query('SELECT `id`, `name` FROM `categorias` ORDER BY name ASC');
    $items = $db->query('SELECT items.id, items.name, items.description, items.price, items.image,items.opciones,items.extras, categorias.name AS category FROM items LEFT JOIN categorias ON items.category = categorias.id ORDER BY items.id DESC');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Index PHP</title>
    <!--     carpeta assets para archivos del home o el index.php -->
</head>
    <body>
        <ul>
            <?php while($categoria = $categorias->fetch()){
                $categorianame = utf8_encode($categoria['name']);?>
                <li> <a href="#<?php echo $categorianame;?>"><?php echo $categorianame;?></a>  </li>
            <?php } ?>
        </ul>
        <a id="<?php echo $categorianame;?>"></a>
        <?php while($item = $items->fetch()){?>
            <img src="admin/imagenes/img-productos/<?php echo $item['image'];?>" alt="<?php echo $item['name'];?>">
            <p><b>Name:</b><?php echo utf8_encode($item['name']);?></p>
            <p><b>Descripcion:</b><?php echo utf8_encode($item['description']);?></p>
            <p><b>Opciones:</b><?php echo utf8_encode($item['opciones']);?></p>
            <p><b>Extras:</b><?php echo utf8_encode($item['extras']);?></p>
            <p><b>Precio:</b> ¢ <?php echo number_format($item['price'],0);?></p>
        <?php }
            Database::disconnect();
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Deberías aclarar qué motor de base de datos usas

Comment: y ¿cuál es el problema puntual con este código?

Comment: a los productos deberias ponerle un campo categoria en el cual irá el id o el nombre de la categoria, asi al hacer la consulta a la BD obtendrias los productos cuyo id o nombre sea igual a la categoria elegida

Comment: El motor de base de datos  es MySQL

Comment: Los productos ya tienen un campo llamado categoría en el cual cada uno de ellos se asocia a una categoría.

Comment: Y entonces cual es el problema?

Answer (score 1):

Si la tabla de productos ya tiene el campo en el que asocias el `id` de la categoría, solo debes enviar este valor al momento de hacer el `insert` de un nuevo producto...

```
insert into items (name, description, opciones, extras, price, id_categoria)
values(los, valores, que, envias, desde, el formulario);
```

Luego, para hacer la consulta desde el menú, pasas el `id` de la categoría elegida en el menú, a la cláusula `WHERE` de la consulta...

```
select * from items where id_categoria = $_POST['id_categoria'];
```

**Ojo,** estos ejemplos son ilustrativos, no he tenido en cuenta la parte de seguridad y es vulnerable a ataques por inyección `sql`

Comment: Muchas Gracias ...me sirvio

Comment: Recuerda aceptar la pregunta con el check que aparece a la izquierda para que sirva como referencia a futuros visitantes y de paso, para que ambos ganemos reputación.